# Google conversational action voice based alternative

Tags: actions-on-google, voice, google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home

With the conversational actions being [sunsetted](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset#what_will_happen_to_non-conversational_action_development_paths), I am looking for alternatives for an application I was hoping to build. It was a simple project in which you asked your assistant (home or android) a question and then it would send that question as an http request to an api. Then read aloud the response.

The interaction being completely verbal and accessible without a screen is important to me, but I cannot find any way to create add a custom response to the google assistant. Of course these seems trivial with conversational actions, but does anyone have a suggestion for what I should use instead?

#### Options I have looked into

App actions - This requires the use of a screen as it simply links to the app which you specify. Also requires an app...

Dialog flow - Apparently connection with the google assistant is also being depreciated: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/aog

Answer (score 1):

[The Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) is one of the ways to interact with Assistant without a screen. It lets you add voice control, natural language understanding to your project. Your project captures an utterance, sends it to the Google Assistant, and receives a spoken audio response in addition to the raw text of the utterance. However, this won't provide a way to create custom responses, or control what assistant gives back as a response.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! Unfortunately a custom responses is an important aspect to my issue so I don't think this would work for me.